# How do I set two image source with one stream

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this code snippet

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
 {    
              stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker>().GetImageStreamAsync();

                 if (stream != null)
                 {

                     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                     {
                         ImageOne.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                         ImageTwo.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

                     });

                 }
}
```

The problem with the code is that only ImageTwo.Source gets set (because it is the last one). How do I set both ImageOne and ImageTwo with the same stream? Is there a better way to do this then what i am doing?

Comment: I would expect only imageOne to be set. Are you sure it sets imageTwo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker>().GetImageStreamAsync();
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()); });
                image2.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()); });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get it doing this way:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{    
    stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker().GetImageStreamAsync();

    if (stream != null)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            var source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            ImageOne.Source = source;
            ImageTwo.Source = source;
        });
    }
}
```

You should test, I don't have tried it.

Comment: ironically, i solve the issue by return a stream array instead of a stream...thanks for the help